# How to create a generic Add Method for two values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics

For example if both values are int type it adds them.... ie `2+2=4`

if both values are float....ie `2.2+2.3=4.5`
or if one value is string and second is int...ie `1 + Pak=1Pak`

We will get these two values from user using tfwo textboxes

Comment: Suppose I typed `007` into your textbox. Is it `7` or `James Bond`

Comment: @m.qayyum sir you are trying to fit a square peg in a round hole... C# is a strongly typed language and that does not lead well to interpretation of entered content by sniffing... Probably would be better to try javascript or another backend language such as PHP...

Comment: Or if I type `1.` , would it mean a double or `first` as in some languages

Comment: What if I type `3*8` or `1/2` or `9.00` or `3,000` or `$4.03` or..... anyone see the problem here?

Comment: This is some kind of `give me your algorithm and I'll give you a way to break it`

Comment: its like trying to use Regex to parse a paragraph into verbs and nouns given the context... Highly involved and easy to screw up and dependent on interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way of doing it. Without having to convert to string and than back to numeric.

```
public object Add(IConvertible a, IConvertible b)
{
    if(IsNumeric(a) && IsNumeric(b))
        return a.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + b.ToDouble(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return a.ToString() + b.ToString();
}

public static bool IsNumeric(object o)
{
    var code = (int)Type.GetTypeCode(o.GetType());
    return code >= 4 && code <= 15;
}
```

Comment: magnus is getting the type code of the returned function and if its a number from 4 to 15 then its a type of numeric

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using generics. You'll receive `string` from your textbox anyway. The only thing to do is to implement it "manually" exactly this way as you said:

```
public string TrySumTwoStrings(string input1, string input2)
{
    double numeric1, numeric2;
    if (Double.TryParse(input1, out numeric1) && Double.TryParse(input2, out numeric2))
        return (numeric1 + numeric2).ToString();
    return input1 + input2;
}
```

There's no way to use generics if we have no different types (everything is typed as `string` here).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't, generics cannot be constrained in a way to support arithmetic operators (or concatenation). You would need to create overloads.

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
public double Add(double x, double y)
public decimal Add(decimal x, decimal y)
// etc.
```

Of course, you still have the problem of determining how exactly to parse your data. The source being a TextBox, the data will inherently be strings. You will have to determine which type of number it should be, if any.

If doing this for a real application, you shouldn't have this problem. Your textbox should be *expected* to receive input from the user in the form of an integer, or a decimal, or a string, etc. If it's not convertible to the proper type, it's an invalid input from your user. You wouldn't want the input to have to be magically deduced.

Comment: "You wouldn't want the input to have to be magically deduced." Tell that to Google when you enter a math equation into the search box.  It's a difficult problem to solve well, but it's by no means something you *wouldn't want to* do, it just may not be worth the amount of effort it'll take.

Comment: I take your point. If you're trying to be Google, you'd deduce it. If you're writing a compiler for C#, you'd deduce it. If you're writing an average line of business application, you'd want proper constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would take some processing the values before hand in order with things like String.PArse, Int.Parse, etc...

Take them in order of compplexity first because 1 will convert to string, however x will not convert to integer or float.

Officially changed my answer to same as comment...

Best suggestion I have on that would be allow the user to select what type to interpret the data as and pass to the appropriate function based on what the user meant, there would be too many ways to interprets char strings to know what the users intention was, code processes logic not intent.

Comment: See my comment above. `007` can be converted to int but m.qayyum wants it as `007` (He/She says so :) )

Comment: Man that seems a lot like asking a program to do what you want not what you have coded for... Best sugestion I have on that would be allow the user to select *what* type to interpret the data as and pass to the appropriate function based on what the user meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Str1 = textBox1.Text.Trim();
string Str2 = textBox2.Text.Trim();

double Num1,num2;

bool isNum1 = double.TryParse(Str1, out Num1);
bool isNum2 = double.TryParse(Str2, out Num2);

if (isNum1 && isNum2)
MessageBox.Show((isNum1 + isNum2).ToString());
else
MessageBox.Show( Str1 + Str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/ The MiscUtil library. It contains some very clever Expression Tree stuff to allow operators with generics. It's not going to work exactly how you want (as others have stated, you can't constrain types to have operators) but it should do exactly what you want.

I don't know how it handles adding different types together though, I've not tried that.